# How can I use sass in my React / webpack project?

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack

I had this working before by importing it with

```
import sass from '../scss/application.scss';
```

> Is this the wrong type of import above?

Now its giving me the following error...

> ERROR in ./app/components/Landing.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'style' in '/Users/sam/Desktop/talkingwith/talkingwith'
>   BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix
>   when using loaders.
>                    You need to specify 'style-loader' instead of 'style'.  @ ./app/components/Landing.js 13:19-54  @ ./app/App.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3333 ./app/App.js

Not sure how I can use SASS in my components now.

edit: my webpack file

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');


var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/App.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig],
  devServer: {
       inline:true,
       contentBase: './public',
       port: 3333
     },
  module: {
    loaders: [{ 
         test: /\.js$/, 
         exclude: /node_modules/, 
         loader: "babel-loader"
      },
        {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              loader: 'style!css!sass'
            }]
  }
};
```

Comment: Like the error states you need to specify the life for your styles. What did differ webpack config file look like?

Comment: added the webpack file for view

Comment: try `loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would post the solution I ended up using

```
  {
     test: /\.scss$/,
     loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what sass library you are using. What works really well for me is using the node-sass library along with sass-loader. https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader
Also it is good practice to use sass-loader with css-loader and style-loader. (as in my example below)

Using sass-loader your webpack.config.js would look something like this.

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');


var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
   './app/App.js'
  ],
  output: {
   path: __dirname + '/public',
   filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig],
  devServer: {
    inline:true,
    contentBase: './public',
    port: 3333
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
     { 
      test: /\.js$/, 
      exclude: /node_modules/, 
      loader: "babel-loader"
     },
     { 
      test: /\.scss$/, 
      loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"] 
     }
   ]
  }
};
```

After you have your webpack.config.js updated to above all you need to do is require your .scss file in your entry point js file, in your case App.js

```
require('path/to/your/style.scss');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am using.  The odd thing is, my project from 2 weeks ago works fine with this exact same webpack config, but this one is failing on the loaders.  I'll give this a try.

Comment: Didn't work.  Just can't seem to include my SASS with any component on this specific project.

Comment: Just to be clear in your entry point js file are you using the require or import statement ? In your post you are using an import statement, did you try to require the scss file instead ? Also are getting the same error ?

Comment: Did you add the loader suffix to all loaders, and it's still giving you the same error to add the suffix ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@import '../scss/application';
```

and in webpack config,

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [
        'style',
        'css',
        'sass'
    ]
}
```